# css not working in html page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a dynamic web application in eclipse. which contains the following project structure.

[image]

Here i have two html pages in WebContent folder and css,images folders.
I have one css file for two html pages.Here this css is applying only for index page ,it is not applying for admin page.

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have added the above line in index and admin pages but,it is applying only for index page ,it is not applying for admin page.

Can any please help me.

Comment: Can you post the content from the `.project` file and the code for the `admin.html` page?

Comment: This should be added in the header of your pages - one page works but other page is not working, so I suspect it's not included in header.

Comment: I added link statement with in head tag only. even though it it is not working for admin page. Can i have multiple html pages in Web Content folder.

Comment: @Asha, yes you can! Do you mind posting some codes from the 3 files?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below path for css. As your index file is in WEB-INF folder, you need to come out of it first, then you need to enter into the css folder. Hopefully, it will work.

```
<link href="./css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: the index.html file is not in WEB-INF! Also, to access parent directory, you need to use "../css/stylesheet.css" (double dots). So, basically, your code is same as that in the question, and should work!  Two mistakes got nullified there! :P

Answer (score 0):

In your HEAD, add this might be worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse working directory always follow this syntex-

```
/ Project_Name / Folder_Name / File_Name.extension
```

so try these in your project for css, images respectively-

```
/brightsymphony/css/stylesheets.css
/brightsymphony/images/logo.png
```